# How to ignore a zero in denominator when computing for mean of rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Supposed I have images A, B and C. They have pixels a, b and c respectively in index (0,0). I want to compute for the mean in index (0,0). Simply (a+b+c)/3. However I want to omit pixel that have nodata or less than or equal to 0. For example if I had c=0 then, (a+b+c)/2 will be the average for that index. I want to know how to do this in raster calculator in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your no-data values is <= 0

```
("A@1" + "B@1" + "C@1")/(("A@1" > 0) + ("B@1" > 0) + ("C@1" > 0))
```